# Physically turn the Raspberry Pi Touch display on and off with a switch

Tags: hardware, power, power-supply, display

I use a Raspberry Pi Touch Display that I connect like shown in the following picture to my Raspberry. The black and red wires are connected to thee GND and 5v pins respectively. Now I want to physically turn off the display while the raspberry is still running.

[image]

Can I just use a normal 12V switch and connect the black wire to the ground and the red to the Acc and Power respectively to be able to turn the display on and off?

[image]

Comment: You could use a normal switch but that device pictured is far from normal.

Comment: top picture ... unplug the red wire ... your switch has to duplicate the breaking of the circuit

Comment: I'd just like to add that some people are saying that after reconnecting the display, it requires some kind of signal from the Pi to turn back on or something...